# 3-dimensional plot of a recursively defined curve?

Tags: tikz-3dplot, pst-3dplot

Is it possible to draw 3-dimensional diagrams with LaTeX, as in the below picture, that come from a recurrence formula?

[image: example-pic]

Comment: Have a look at [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net//tikz/examples/tag/3d/) and at the `pgfplots` documentation.

Comment: related (or dupe?): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181141/automatic-tikz-coordinate-calculations

Comment: @Ruben Not really a duplicate but the thread you posted is indeed related (imho).

Comment: @phx, I was'nt completely certain about it. I would argue: The linked post shows how to generate coordinates recursively, which is kind of the main point of this question. The only new quality here is that it is supposed to be 3-dim. But, I think this can be easily transferred from the other question. I'm not sure whether this is worth to be an own question then...

Comment: What is the formula ?